# Installing Damn Vulnerable Linux on a 16GB USB flash drive

Tags: linux, usb, iso-image

I'm attempting to install Damn Vulnerable Linux onto a 16GB USB flash drive but I'm not sure how. I know that you can't just burn the ISO onto the drive so I have no idea by what means to install it.

My question:

How do I install Damn Vulnerable Linux onto a 16GB USB flash drive?

Comment: Is there anyway to boot to the ISO directly from the boot menu on any computer?

Answer (score 0):

I'd not heard of this until. I googled it, but as it's Debian based I'd expect you can download the iso and use "Unetbootin" to install it to USB. There are versions for both Windows and Linux

Another way (and probably what they are talking about) would be to bit copy the ISO onto the pen drive. This does not work with all distros (but works with many). The Linux tool to do this is "dd" - no doubt there are Windows equivalents.

Comment: unetbootin is often considered outdated.I tend to use rufus these days but there's other similar tools too.

Comment: What would I do to copy it to my pen drive?

Comment: Run unetbootin,, select is and drive and click install

Comment: So when I run the iso off of my flash drive, it gives me a grub rescue screen.

Answer (score -1):

That distro was meant to be run in a VM so that people could easily learn the basics of breaking into a Linux system . Booting the ISO image in VirtualBox or any other desktop virtualization software should be easy. But, because it's so old, it carries outdated software and consequently isn't very good for learning purposes.

These days, we can easily download various kinds of preconfigured VMs to practice against from vulnhub.com or similar sites. There's also hack.me if you want to focus on Webapps.

VulnHub has an [FAQ](https://www.vulnhub.com/faq/) section that you should read before you begin using their VMs. It has some important information about, among others, how to use the VMs and how to keep yourself safe when using them.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Davidgo: You should've checked the question. It's been edited. When I answered, it had this: "I know that DVL is extremely old so if anyone has alternatives, that would be nice too." Don't be trigger happy just because you can.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry.